# How to get a record connected to another record in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

I have a DB entry in MongoDB that stores the name of a context (text), the user who added it, and the statements inside.

However, when I query it, I only get the name of the context and the date of creation, I don't get the user id and the statements.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I could fix it?

My entry in MongoDB is like this:

```json
{
"_id":{"$oid":"615314c9ba504ed1f92af7a7"},
"context":{"contextName":"luchkas1",
"statements":[],
"user":{"_id":{"$oid":"61530ff10eae08c91a0f0794"},"username":"oleg1"},
"createdAt":{"$date":"2021-09-28T13:12:41.335Z"},
"_id":{"$oid":"615314c9ba504ed1f92af7a4"}},
"content":" orange apple"
}
```

Then I am querying it using TypeORM / Nest.Js using the service:

```js
 async getGraphOfContext(contextId: string, maxNodes = 150, addStats = false) {

    const context: Context = await this.contextRepository.findOne(contextId, {
      relations: ['statements', 'user'],
    });

    console.log(context);
 }
```

However, what I get is just

```
Context {
  _id: 615314c9ba504ed1f92af7a7,
  contextName: 'luchkas1',
  createdAt: 2021-09-28T13:12:41.335Z
}
```

So where is the user (id) connected to that context as well as the statements?

When I use my TypeORM configuration with PostregSQL using a similar setup it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the entity relationship is defined correctly?

Comment: @talfreds well this I don't know so well because I'm new to TypeORM

Comment: If you add it to the original post I can take a look. It's probably correct but I'm not sure what else would cause the result you get.